# Getting Js Syntax Error in plugin 'gulp-browserify' while running Gulp Tasks

Tags: node.js, browserify, gulp

I'm running a Node App project built on Express, Jade and Less. I'm using '[Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)' (The streaming build system) along with 'browserify' and 'gulp-browserify'. But when I run Gulp Task its throwing error showing like

```
[gulp] SyntaxError in plugin 'gulp-browserify': <my_project_path>/assets/javascripts/fake_a3100e75.js
```

The file `fake_a3100e75.js` does not seem to exists in directory.

Has anybody come across the same problem? Any solutions highly appreciated?

Answer (score 6):

gulp-browserify isn't a recommended plugin. Its actually blacklisted. This is because Browserify handles its own I/O operations and returns a stream itself, so there's no need for `gulp.src()`. Instead use Browserify or Watchify directly along with vinyl-source-stream to stream it into other plugins. There's a [recipe in the docs here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md).

There's also a good [recipe for handling errors](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/combining-streams-to-handle-errors.md).

[Here's what the task I'm working on looks like right now.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9253918)

Your error pointed to a fake filename because that's what gulp-browserify names the file in a vinyl stream. With the recipes above you name the file yourself with vinyl-source-stream, and that's after the error handler is set on browserify, so you should get proper browserify errors.